# AmStockChart zooms window when window is at the edge

Tags: javascript, amcharts

[Here](https://codepen.io/team/amcharts/pen/25256cb015fc4a624f032409e15c05f6) is an example of the AmSerialChart, in which you can use the scroll button to scroll the window over the data. When you reach the end (or beginning) and continue scrolling, the window will remain the same width.

[Here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/XzoBgE) is another example, using the AmStockChart. The window is zoomed in using a slightly different method: zoomToIndexes does not exist for stockCharts, thus the "zoom" method is used.

```
var chartData = generateChartData();
var chart = AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv", {
    "categoryAxesSettings": {
        minPeriod: "fff",
    },
    "chartScrollbarSettings": {
        graph: "g1",
        usePeriod: "fff",
    },
    "dataSets": [
        {
            mouseWheelZoomEnabled: false,
            categoryField: "date",
            dataProvider: chartData,
            fieldMappings: [
                {
                    fromField: "gg1",
                    toField: "gg1"
                }, {
                    fromField: "gg2",
                    toField: "gg2"
                }
            ],
        }
    ],
    "mouseWheelScrollEnabled": true,
    "panels": [
        {
            stockGraphs: [
                {
                    id: "g1",
                    valueField: "gg1",
                    type: "step",
                }
            ],
        }, {
            stockGraphs: [
                {
                    valueField: "gg2",
                    type: "step",
                }
            ],
        }
    ],
    "type": "stock",
});
```

When you scroll to the left in the StockChart, the window will reduce in size!
So far, I have not been able to identify a reason why the SerialChart does not reduce the size, while the StockChart does. I did find a post on SO that says to set mouseWheelZoomEnabled to false, however this option is for the SerialChart, not the StockChart.

I guess it is possible to add a listner to the scroll event, and prevent the window from reducing in size when it collides with the left or right side, however... I assume there is a better reason.

My question: How to prevent the window from reducing in size in the AmStockChart?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set [`minSelectedTime`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptstockchart/PanelsSettings#minSelectedTime) in the `panelsSettings` to achieve the same behavior in a stock chart. Note that this will also prevent the scrollbar from zooming to a smaller time frame when dragging the sliders directly:

```
var chart = AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv", {
  panelsSettings: {
    mouseWheelZoomEnabled: false, 
    minSelectedTime: 4.32e+9,
    mouseWheelScrollEnabled: true
  },
  // ...
});
```

[Demo](https://codepen.io/team/amcharts/pen/43f291220e66253d5700402e70606773?editors=0010)